# Using Jupyter notebook for Java

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook

I've used the Jupyter notebook quite a lot for my Python projects, but now I have to work on something in Java. So I was wondering if I could get Jupyter to work with Java?

After some searching I think I understand that you can install different kernels for other languages, with a list of kernels [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels). But I don't see one for Java there. The reason I think there is a working solution is [this notebook](https://athena.brynmawr.edu/jupyter/hub/dblank/public/CS206%20Data%20Structures/2016-Spring/Notebooks/IntroToJava.ipynb), showing of a Java 9 notebook. Does anyone know how to set this up?

I'm on macOS Sierra if it matters.

Comment: There seems to be a kernel around, but apparently it's currently not functional. See: https://github.com/Bachmann1234/java9_kernel

Comment: @cel I found that too, but figured it was outdated due to the not functional part. And it hasn't been updated in a bit either, so it doesn't seem likely that it will be fixed... But is that really all there is?

Comment: Scijava fails if you use scanner or try to define an array. No help with the problem either, I suggest you try something else. Wish I knew what, but java on jupyterlab seems like a lost cause.

Comment: Hi I'm currently working on the task about turning parts of the logic in Java source codes into JupyterNotebook, can these Kernals help?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

IJava available at https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava requires JDK 9. The build process for my iMac (MacOS 10.13.5) worked like a charm and within 10 minutes, I could start programming interactively in Java within Jupyter.

Comment: This still works well, even though the last GitHub commit was `a03ad77 on 9 Dec 2019` (as of 19 Jan 22)

Comment: after installing the kernel, is there a way to select it in VSCode?

Answer (score 12):

While doing a similar search, I found an option that may meet your needs:

SciJava Jupyter Kernel
https://github.com/scijava/scijava-jupyter-kernel

I have not actually run Java against this kernel yet, but it's documentation claims to support Java among a number of other scripting languages.

It is constructed to run ImageJ ("an open source Java image processing program"): https://imagej.net/Scripting#Supported_languages

Jupyter Kernels List (reference):
https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels

Comment: Co-maintainer of SciJava Jupyter Kernel here. Just a heads up that we have retired support for this kernel. I recommend using IJava instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Zeppelin](http://zeppelin.apache.org/) notebook instead. Apache Zeppelin is build on the JVM.

Comment: I've tried Zeppelin for Java and found it limited compared to support for Kotlin and Scala. For example, you cannot pass values from one cell to the next when using Java. [ZeppelinContext search in Zeppelin GitHub](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/search?q=%22extends+ZeppelinContext%22) and [Apache Zeppelin Context z.put() share data between cells in Java notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66979130/apache-zeppelin-context-z-put-share-data-between-cells-in-java-notebook)

Answer (score -1):

You can integrate Visual Studio Code with Anaconda-Navigator. After installing anaconda, run this command in cmd: 'conda install ipykernel'. This should solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Vihaan, your answer helps in doing the set-up needed to use Jupyter notebooks for python programming, not for java programming, which is what this question was  asking about.

Answer (score -3):

In the list of kernels, there is also a Scala kernel, which is based on Java.

Comment: I guess that's nice - if you use Scala. Not much help that it is based on Java when it can't run Java code...

Comment: Scala can run java code. They both compile down to byte code